# Working with hashMaps

Tags: java

I want to avoid the use of for loop for iterating through the HaspMap for finding a key and then picking up the value corresponding to that key...Can anyone help me to implement the same...?
Below given is my code using forloop which i would like to replace with containsKey function()

```
 for (Entry<Long, Long> entry : sessionTimeStampHash.entrySet()) 
 //if(sessionTimeStampHash.containsKey(sessionID)) 
 {
    if (entry.getKey().equals(sessionID)) 
    {
        sessionTimeStamp = entry.getValue();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I would recommend you to read some basic tutorials on Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need a loop at all. Maps are *associative collections*, which means they are designed and optimized for fast key-based lookup. A map is meant to be used this way:

```
sessionTimeStamp = sessionTimeStampHash.get(sessionID);
if (sessionTimeStamp != null) {
  // do something with sessionTimeStamp
}
```

Or using `containsKey()`:

```
if (sessionTimeStampHash.containsKey(sessionID)) {
  sessionTimeStamp = sessionTimeStampHash.get(sessionID);
  // do something with sessionTimeStamp
}
```

See the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) to learn more about Maps and other collections.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(sessionTimeStampHash.contains(sessionID) {
  sessionTimeStamp  = sessionTimeStampHash.get(sessionID);
} else {
   //Create session 
  sessionTimeStamp = getSessionTimeStamp();
  sessionTimeStampHash.put(sessionId, sessionTimeStamp);
}
```

[More](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)